# UIScrollView drag to right or left

Tags: iphone

I have a UIScrollView with 5 page. At last page, if I scroll to right I will display a new UIView. (If i scroll to left it will back page 4th ).

So, how I can know UIScrollView is drag to right?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you clarify more on exactly what you want?

If you're asking for when the UIScrollView starts scrolling, then you could use the following method from UIScrollViewDelegate:

`- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`